# Firebase Realtime Database - cannot read document as json/dictionary

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my realtime database I have a path /stats which contains a set of documents.

[image: My firebase real database structure]

I want to using the python sdk get the /stats document as a dict. My code looks like that

```
path = "/stats"
ref = db.reference(path, firebase_app)
document = ref.get()
print(document)
```

And the output is

```
[None, {'name': 'Full Time Statistics', 'thumbnail': 'https://***', 'url': 'https://***'}]
```

which is a list not a dictionary. How to change it and read this document path as a dictionary something like that

```
{"1": {'name': 'Full Time Statistics', 'thumbnail': 'https://***', 'url': 'https://***'}}
```

On the other hand I can get other documents with similar structures as a dictionary with no issue. Why is it like that and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things are happening here:

1. Since you are retrieving `/stats` you are getting all nodes under it. Since this is a repeated list and Firebase Realtime Database keys are strings, you'd normally get a dictionary (with the keys in the dictionary being the keys in the JSON).
2. Since your keys are numeric values, Firebase "thinks" you are trying to store an array/list and it tries to coerce the data into an array for you. That's why you get a `None` entry in the list: that's Firebase filling in the zeroth element for you.

There's unfortunately no way to disable this array coercion. I typically get around it by prefixing the keys with a fixed string, so that Firebase bypasses its array logic. So:

```
stats: {
  stat1: { ... },
  stat2: { ... }
}
```

Also see:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html)